# rpi-gpio pin always high/low

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

we are using rpi-gpio and node.js to read/write to
raspberry version 1 pins.

we have a led connected to gnd (pin 3) and gpio4 (pin 7).

using write works perfectly:

```
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_OUT, write);

function write() {
    gpio.write(7, true, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Written to pin');
    });
}
```

although using the read function

```
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_IN, readInput);

function readInput() {
    gpio.read(7, function(err, value) {
        console.log('The value is ' + value);
    });
}
```

leads to the following behavior:

1) the led is turned off
2) the status of the gpio pin is always true

setting the the port to "true" so the led is light makes
no difference. when reading the pin the led is off and pin is true.

the same but inverse is with pin 11, 12 - led is off and pin false.

using a listener for value changes on the specific pin works ... 
although i really want to read the pin-value on demand!

Comment: Which gpio library are you using?

Comment: i'm using rpi-gpio. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio. but i tried pi-gpio.js also, the same behavior!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For writing, you set the GPIO pin as an output (which is good). But when you try to 'read' you set the GPIO pin as an input which changes the mode of the pin. So try to remove:

```
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_IN, readInput);
```

From the Raspberry Pi forum:

> Five of the 17 available GPIO lines are
>   pulled high by default (the rest are pulled low). The numbers are
>   GPIO0/2, GPIO1/3, GPIO4, GPIO7 and GPIO8.

Comment: i already set the DIR_IN for reading from the pin, but the value is always true (eg. pin 7) or false (pin 11) no matter if the pin was set high or low. we tried it with a led connected to pin 7. we set the pin to high - led was on. then we tried the read the status of the pin via a seperate call - the read operation seemed to reset the pin so the led was off, the pin itself was true - the same operation with the pin set to false, led > OFF - the result when reading the pin status > pin 7 > true.

Answer (score 1):

Setup gpio pin to DIR_OUT for write. After write, read the pin without setup gpio again.  Here is my code using gpio promise api:

```
    var gpio = require('rpi-gpio').promise
            
    const pin = 7
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.DIR_OUT)
        .then(() => {
            gpio.write(pin, true)
                .then(() => {
                    gpio.read(pin)
                        .then(status => {
                            console.log('The status of the pin ', pin, ' is ', status)
                        })
                        .catch(err => {console.log(err.toString())})
                }).catch(err => {console.log(err.toString())})
         }).catch(err => {console.log(err.toString())})
```